# Issue Counting Rows in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a table in Hive. When I run the following I always get 0 returned:

```
select count(*) from <table_name>;
```

Event though if I run something like:

```
select * from <table_name> limit 10;
```

I get data returned.
I am on Hive 1.1.0. 
I believe the following two issues are related:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11266

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7400

Is there anything I can do to workaround this issue?

Comment: Which one you are using hive CLI or Beeline?

Comment: Beeline, just ran with Hive CLI (never even used it before). That works. If you'd submit the answer I'd accept it thanks. Feel a bit silly.

Comment: Generally speaking, using statistics to return information *guaranteed to be stale* is an abomination. Anyway, you can make sure that Hive always generates a MapReduce job by running sthg like `select count(*) from WTF where SOME_COL is not null` if you know for sure that `SOME_COL` always has a value (e.g. an ID)

Comment: I rarely use hive directly so my knowledge of the differences between hive CLI and beeline is limited. This was just for an integration activity test. When I call the modified operation it looks like it starts a hive task but still get 0 rows back.

Comment: Looks like some issue with configuration, May be hive CLI using some other metastore and beeline is using something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is the old and outdated statistics of the table. Try issuing this command which should solve the problem.

```
ANALYZE TABLE <table_name> COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```

When you import the table first there may be various reasons the statistics is not updated by Hive services. I am still looking for options and properties to make it right.